# How to change Parse Push Notification icon programmatically?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, android-notifications

I use `Parse` `push notification` for sending some messages to users.
but I wanna change notification icon for every message programmatically.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the `onPushReceived` and create your own notification and set the icon.
The easiest way should be passing the icon on PushService.subscribe() calling `PushService.subscribe(context, channel, activity, icon)`

```
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(context, SomeActivity.class, R.drawable.customIcon)

PushService.subscribe(context, "ChannelName", SomeActivity.class, R.drawable.customIcon)
```

If you want just to use a different icon add this to your manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/push_icon"/>
```